# Use of prepositions in and for with Present Perfect tense

Tags: grammar, prepositions, present-perfect

I would be thankful if  any native could tell me whether the following sentence is correct - I am learning the language -.

- I haven't spoken to my sister **for / in** a few days. Are **for** and **in** both correct? Is there any difference of usage -  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Both are common, at least in "American English", and they mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: It's worth noting that the ***in*** version is very much [an emerging **American** usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=haven%27t+seen+him+in%2Chaven%27t+seen+him+for&year_start=1915&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20seen%20him%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20not%20seen%20him%20for%3B%2Cc0) that probably doesn't sit well with many UK speakers. When speaking of future events, *I'll see him **for** a week* is very different to *I'll see him **in** a week*, so it just seems confusing to use them interchangeably for a *past* context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- What's interests me is that ***for*** could be ambiguous (context obviously clears things up immediately)  But when  I say I haven't spoken to her for a few days it could mean I've never had a  conversation that lasted for a few days or it could mean that it's been a few days since we've spoken, whereas I think with ***in*** no such ambiguity exists.  It makes more sense with a different verb:  "I've haven't driven with her for a week" could mean I've never taken a cross-country trip with her or that I'm her driving instructor and her last lesson was last week.